# gradle sync faild in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am using Android studio 1.5 and I am receiving

> gradle project sync failed basic functionality will not work properly

I clicked the sync button and then "invalidate and start", and the error message is:

> Error: connection refused: connect

How can I fix this?

**build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.com.bt_11"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

Comment: You might be getting a DOS (Denial of Service) for some reason, or the servers are too busy with too many connections. try again in a few minutes. or just restart AS

Comment: 1.build -> clean project. 2.invalidate cache and restart.

Comment: What happens when you run ``./gradlew build --info` in the command line? That should give you more info on what's actually happening - where it's having a problem.